# When would a team pass on Family Feud?

Tags: family-feud

After winning a toss-up question on *Family Feud*, the member of the winning team is then asked if they want to pass or play that round.  Most teams play.  Is there a strategy where passing is the optimal move?  Maybe if the question is too difficult or obscure?

Comment: Not sure if this really fits on this exchange. Seems more like a game theory question than anything else.

Comment: @SGR Can you recommend a Stack Exchange site where I can ask this question?

Comment: @ChanandlerBong I'm not sure this qualifies as reality tv, as it's a game show.

Comment: You're right, per [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reality_television) game shows don't qualify as such. I've removed the tag.

Comment: @JAL Possibly stats.stackexchange.com, but I'd recommend asking the chat before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) They can't think of any other answers, so they don't want to lose any points they might earn in a steal by the other team.

AND/OR

B) They think it will be easier to steal the points from the other team than to get all of the points themselves.